# How can I add an icon to Material-UI Select?

Tags: reactjs, angular-material, material-ui, material-design

I need to add a location icon to react Material-UI `Select` options. But there is no option for that...I read API docs in select but can't find a related option. So I really need your help with that. Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

I  found code like this. but not working properly.

```
<div id='location-box'>
  <Select>
    <MenuItem value="">
      <ListItemIcon>
        <LocationOnIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</div>
```

Comment: check this example [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/91q9lyn274)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can override the `renderValue` callback to render the selected text with whatever icon you want. Remember to set `displayEmpty` to force the `Select` display an empty value if no option is selected. For reference, see the full list of API [here](https://mui.com/api/select/):

```
<Select
  displayEmpty
  renderValue={(value) => {
    return (
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", gap: 1 }}>
        <SvgIcon color="primary">
          <LocationOnIcon />
        </SvgIcon>
        {value}
      </Box>
    );
  }}
  {...}
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Hi, it does work properly when the value and the showed element are the same, but how to do when they are differently? Example:

 {elencoEsercizi.map(option =>
<MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.id}> {option.NameOfItem}</MenuItem> )}

any suggestion ? Thanks !